# How to send RSA open key over tcp?

Tags: tcp, openssl, rsa

So, the question is how to correctly make a binary data of RSA *rsa key?
I do

```
RSA *rsa = RSA_generate_key(2048, 65537, 0, 0);
uchar *pp = (uchar *)malloc(2560);
int bytes = i2d_RSAPublicKey(rsa, &pp);
write(client, pp, bytes);
```

and reciever does d2i_RSAPublicKey and the program crashes. what i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't malloc `pp` yourself, instead set it NULL. `i2d_RSAPublicKey` will do the malloc for you and set pp to point to the newly malloced public key.